# Make graphics move on key events

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, keylistener

I'm trying to make a circle capable of moving when the keys "i, j, k, l" are pressed (as arrow keys) and stop when released. Tried creating a Timer in order to wait a second before moving again so the animation is appreciable, but since I created the 'while(!quit)' loop, no graphics move or show. Could you please indicate my errors please?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Event_test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean quit = false;

        JFrame Window = new JFrame("Event_test");
        MyCanvas WCanvas = new MyCanvas();
        KeyCatcher k = new KeyCatcher();

        WCanvas.addKeyListener(k);


        Window.getContentPane().add(WCanvas);
        Window.setSize(640, 360);
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        new Notification(1);

        while(!quit)
        {
            WCanvas.update(WCanvas.getGraphics());

            if(!Notification.flag)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Notification.flag = false;
                System.out.println("tic");
                /*
                CONTROLS:
                */

                if(KeyCatcher.KEYS[0])
                {
                    MyCanvas.x--;
                }
                if(KeyCatcher.KEYS[1])
                {
                    MyCanvas.y++;
                }
                if(KeyCatcher.KEYS[2])
                {
                    MyCanvas.x++;
                }
                if(KeyCatcher.KEYS[3])
                {
                    MyCanvas.y--;
                }
                if(KeyCatcher.KEYS[4])
                {
                    quit = true;
                }

                new Notification(1);
            }


        }
    }
}

class MyCanvas extends Canvas
{
    static int x, y;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g = this.getGraphics();
        MyClass.drawSomething(g, x, y);
    }
}

class MyClass
{

    public static void drawSomething(Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}

class KeyCatcher implements KeyListener
{

    static boolean KEYS[] = new boolean[5];


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'j'/*IZQ*/)
        {
            KEYS[0] = true;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'i'/*ARR*/)
        {
            KEYS[1] = true;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'l'/*DER*/)
        {
            KEYS[2] = true;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'k'/*ABA*/)
        {
            KEYS[3] = true;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'q'/*QUIT*/)
        {
            KEYS[4] = true;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'j'/*IZQ*/)
        {
            KEYS[0] = false;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'i'/*ARR*/)
        {
            KEYS[1] = false;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'l'/*DER*/)
        {
            KEYS[2] = false;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'k'/*ABA*/)
        {
            KEYS[3] = false;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'q'/*QUIT*/)
        {
            KEYS[4] = false;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }
}

class Notification{
    static boolean flag = false;
    Timer timer;

    Notification(int seconds)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Task(), seconds*1000);
    }

    class Task extends TimerTask
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //What task does:
            flag = true;
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: while loop likely eating all the CPU.  Try putting in a `Thread.sleep(16)` at the end.  If that doesn't work, is the program still responsive at all while it's running?

Comment: Don't even use a while loop -- use a Swing Timer -- as per camickr's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is about Swing (not AWT) so:

1. Don't extend Canvas. Instead custom painting is done by extending a JPanel
2. Don't override paint(...). Custom painting is done by overrding paintComponent(...)
3. Don't use a TimerTask. Instead use a Swing Timer.
4. Don't use the getGraphics() method. See point 2.
5. Don't invoke update(...). You just invoke repaint() on the component and it will paint iself.
6. Don't use a while loop. That is the reason for using the Swing Timer.
7. Don't start variable names with an upper case character. Follow Java naming conventions.
8. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for basic painting examples to get you started.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The `Keyboard Animation` example addresses many of these issues.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long replying. Thank you so much for your answer, the last link you provided really helps me a lot.